# C++ Builder E2303 Type name expected

Tags: c++builder

I am attempting to use the HP APDK with C++ Builder in RAD Studio XE5. I need to derive a class PlatformServices (or any name of my choosing) from HP's base class SystemServices. Here is my header PlatformServices.h:

```
/***************************************************************************\
    APDK Platform Services
\***************************************************************************/

#ifndef _H_PLATFORMSERVICES
#define _H_PLATFORMSERVICES

#include    "header.h"                          //  HP APDK General Header

//  class SystemServices {
//  };

class PlatformServices : public SystemServices {
    ~PlatformServices ();
    PlatformServices ();
};

#endif
```

Compiled as-is, I get the error:

```
[bcc32 Error] PlatformServices.h(13): E2303 Type name expected
  Full parser context
    PlatformServices.cpp(5): #include PlatformServices.h
    PlatformServices.h(13): class PlatformServices
```

But if I comment out the #include and uncomment the definition for an empty class named SystemServices, the code compiles without error.

I can preprocess the code as-is (in Project Manager, right click on PlatformServices and select Preprocess) and I can see that the #include defines a well formed SystemServices class.

I've also disabled pre-compiled headers.

This seems like a compiler error, but it's a poor workman who blames his tools. I just can't believe C++ Builder would choke on something this basic, yet I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Help!

P.S. I've posted the full code and project files at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sn1377y59r3idtz/apdk.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SystemServices` is declared in the `apdk` namespace, so you need to specify that in your code, either directly:

```
class PlatformServices : public apdk::SystemServices
```

Or with a `using namespace` statement:

```
using namespace apdk;

class PlatformServices : public SystemServices
```

Comment: Correct. Specifically, bracketing the contents of the source and header files with the name space macros APDK_BEGIN_NAMESPACE and APDK_END_NAMESPACE, just like the source and header files for the base class SystemServices, solves the problem. Thank You.

Comment: From a design point of view, it is not good practice to inject your code into someone else's namespace. Sure, the compiler will accept it, but it will muddle your own code's management.  You can use code from someone else's namespace, but keep it separate from your own code.